# How to check the text of a tweet for a specific keyword from an array in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter, tweepy

Hi I am having an issue with searching for a specific piece of text within a tweet. I am currently using tweepy to stream tweets based on an array of keywords (called filterKeywords), however i want a specific function to be done depending on what keyword the tweet was filtered by.

I load the tweet into a JSON variable and try to use a for loop to cycle through the filterKeywords array in my on_data method, performing an IF statement to search if the current element on the filterKeywords array matches any text within the 'text' tag of the JSON tweet, however it doesnt seem to be filtering anything and seems to go to the else statement in my if statement immediately. Here is my code below. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import tweepy
import pymongo
import json

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filterKeywords = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Apple',        'Google', 'Amazon', 'EBay', 'Diageo',
              'General Motors', 'General Electric', 'Telefonica', 'Rolls Royce', 'Walmart', 'HSBC', 'BP',
              'Investec', 'WWE', 'Time Warner', 'Santander Group']


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def __init__(self, api):
    self.api = api
    super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()
    try:
        global conn
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        print "Connected successfully!!!"
        global db
        db = conn.mydb
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print "Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e
        conn


def on_data(self, data):
    datajson = json.loads(data)
    for word in filterKeywords:
       if word in datajson['text']:
        collection = db[word]
        collection.insert(datajson)
        print('Tweet found filtered by ' + word)
    else:
        print('')



def on_error(self, status_code):
    return True  # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    return True  # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
```

sapi.filter(track=filterKeywords)

Comment: can you post a `data`

Comment: Its too long to post as a whole so here is a link to it in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ejbhj88m)

Comment: i think `data['text']` contain '\u0e44\u0e2b\u0e25\u0e48' chars.So may it have to be encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_data(self, data):
    datajson = json.loads(data)
    if any([i for i in filterKeywords if i in datajson["text"]]):
        """Do Desired function"""
    else:
        print('if statement not working')
```

Simple mistake on your program, even after `if` condition works it may enter `else` in the next iteration.

**From your comments** If you wish to avoid `keyError 'test'`.Rewrite your function like

```
def on_data(self, data):
datajson = json.loads(data)
for word in filterKeywords:
    if datajson.get('text') and word in datajson['text']:
        collection = db[word]
        collection.insert(datajson)
        print('Tweet found filtered by ' + word)
else:
    print('')
```

Comment: Ill try that loop now to see if it can achieve what I want. Thanks

Comment: Ok the if statement works (it was missing a ']') but my function wants to print a statement based on the keyword the specific tweet was filtered by (I can then apply that code later to creating a mongodb collection based on the the keyword) however when I use `print('tweet filtered by ' + i)` it doesnt seem to recognise i? am I reading this completely wrong? Its a real possibility

Comment: Upon further inspection the if statement only takes in the last element of the array apparently. So it only picks up 'Santander Group'.

Comment: oh did you want to save `data['text']` to database if filterwords contain?

Comment: Yea I wanted it to save to to an Apple MongoDB if the filter was triggered by the element 'Apple' in the fliterKeywords array and do that for every element contained within the filterKeywords array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you included "Twitter" in the filter keywords, and that matches almost everything (not only the text are used for filtering, but some other fields as well). Try removing it from the filter keywords.

Comment: Thats exactly what the problem was! I knew it was a simple question staring me in the face but I think looking at a computer screen too long had made it harder for me to notice this. Thanks very much!!

Comment: I have now added code so it saves it to a mongodb collection based on the filter word but after so many tweets streamed, it throws a keyerror based on 'text' (KeyError: 'text'). The new method has been edited into the original question

Comment: Maybe just a tweet without a 'text' field? You should check if datajson contains key 'text' before accessing it? But i think it is completely different than your original question.

Comment: Would not all tweets have a 'text' field? I kinda assumed that was a pre-requisite of a tweet?